# Where do we give the table-name?

Tags: php, mysql

I am learning to connect an android app to a sqlDatabase with the help PHP scripts and this is what the php scripts basically look like:

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', '*********');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '*********'); 

$con = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
```

Why is that we do not need the table-name here? A database can have multiple tables. Or do we mention that in the app?

Comment: because we don't need table name to connect with the database ... We need it when we query it

Comment: ThankU. I now realize how stupid my question was!!

Comment: Well, as Selvin said the TABLE name is not needed to connect. What you need is the database name. Actually you're passing 3 params to the new mysqli function, but there should be 4. `$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tablename is given in the query after connection is established